# Как сравнить числовые данные, переданные с помощью нескольких интентов в другое активити

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Есть активити1, которое передает в активити2 для счетчика количество миллисекунд. Количество миллисекунд может быть разным (в зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажата на активити1).Счетчик в активити2 должен принимать эти значение миллисекунд.

В активити1 код для передачи данных такой:

```
 int SEKOND; 

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button_dif
                SEKOND = 5000;
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("sekondDif",SEKOND);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button_is:
                SEKOND = 50000;
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
                intent1.putExtra("sekondIs",SEKOND);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;

        }
    }
```

В ативити2 код получения интентов такой:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

int id0 = extras.getInt("sekondDif");
int id1 = extras.getInt("sekondIs");
```

Т.е. число передано и извлечено.

Далее есть счетчик, вместо id которого нужно поставить либо данные из id0 либо из id1, в зависимости от того, какой интент был получен:

```
 new CountDownTimer(id, 1000) {}
```

Сама логика такая: на активити1 есть разные button. Если кликнуть по  button1, то при переходе на активити2 в счетчике должно быть выставлено одно количество миллисекунд, если кликнуть  на активтити1 по button2, то в счетчике должно быть выставлено другое количество миллисекунд.

Помогите, пожалуйста, связать эти условия (секунды счетчика на втором активити и выбор кнопки на первом активити ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ваша проблема в том, что вы не знаете во второй активити какое именно значение было передано из первой, то вы можете, при вытаскивании данных из интента указывать значение по умолчанию для отсутствующих данных и проверяя ваши переменные второй активити на предмет равенства значения по умолчанию вызывать метод нужный передавая туда нужную переменную.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

//зададим -1 как значение по умолчанию. 
//им будет инициализированна переменная, если в Bundle нет искомого ключа.
//если этот аргумент не указать и значения по ключу нет, то присвоится 0
int id0 = extras.getInt("sekondDif", -1);
int id1 = extras.getInt("sekondIs", -1);

if(id0 != -1)
{ //значит получено "sekondDif" }
else if(id1 != -1)
{ //значит получено "sekondIs" }
```

---

Также можно проверять есть ли определённый ключ в `Bundle` методом `contains(String key)`

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения логики работы программы ваш подход в решении этой задачи логически неверен.

В решении **именно вашей** задачи вообще не требуется слать какие то разные интенты и что то там потом определять какой из них какой:

```
int second;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_dif
            second = 5000;
            break;
        case R.id.button_is:
            second = 50000;
            break;
    }

  intent.putExtra("sekond",second);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Activity2:**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

int second = extras.getInt("second");
new CountDownTimer(second, 1000) {};
```

---

Что касается решения для вопроса **в общем случае**, то правильно не слать разные значения одним из интентов и потом пытаться определить, в каком же он отправлен, а одним интентом слать значение, другим - признак (ключ) о типе переданного значения:

```
int second; 
final int DIF = 1;
final int IS = 2;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_dif
            second = 5000;
            intent.putExtra("key",DIF);
            break;
        case R.id.button_is:
            second = 50000;
            intent.putExtra("key",IS);
            break;
    }

  intent.putExtra("sekond",second);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Activity2:**

```
final int DIF = 1;
final int IS = 2;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

int key = extras.getInt("key");
int second = extras.getInt("second");

switch (key){
    case DIF: difMethod(second); // действия при переданном значении dif
              break;
    case IS: isMethod(second); // действия при переданном значении is
              break;
}
```

Вы можете сделать отдельный класс констант и хранить их все там, а не инициализировать в каждом активити

Замечания - по [конвенции разработчика Android](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ буквами в ["змеином стиле"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) пишутся имена констант. Имена переменных пишутся в [lowerCamelCase-стиле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) - имя начинается с маленькой буквы, Отдельные слова в имени пишутся без пробелов с большой буквы. Этой конвенции рекомендуется придерживаться всем разработчикам.